# Angular Boilerplate

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There seem to be quite some angular.js boilerplate-kits to get started; angular-seed, some using requirejs and so on, but lots of the ones I found appear to be quite dated. Being new to angular: is there any boilerplate "to go", something hyped everybody uses? I'm looking for a good, proved way to give my app structure.

Things I could find so far include

- [yeoman/generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular)
- [angular/angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed)
- [CaryLandholt/AngularFun](https://github.com/CaryLandholt/AngularFun)
- [angular-app/angular-app](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app)

Comment: "Is there something hyped everybody uses?"

Comment: I don't think you'll go wrong with any of those.  I used Angular-seed as a basis for my big project.   It has everything you need to learn angular without a lot of extras.  It helped out most by having the unit and e2e tests preconfigured.. I see a lot of people on here that have trouble getting those up and running.   AngularFun looks like it might be good for coffeescript/less people, and angular-app might be a good example for full crud kinds of apps.

Comment: https://github.com/brnrajoriya/Angular-Boilerplate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no one correct way to structure every application.
And definitely nothing more mainstream than what you've already found.

Start from that and work your way towards what's optimal for your current application.
I would recommend a simpler structure at first (naturally separate vendor from application files, CSS etc.), then refactoring as you go along.

Comment: Thanks, just wondered if there was that "mainstream" boilerplate. I think for some languages or frameworks these do exist.

Comment: Yeoman would be closest to that, but I don't use it personally.

Comment: https://github.com/brnrajoriya/Angular-Ready-To-Use-Boilerplate

Answer (score 11):

I agree with finishingmove, it depends on your project.

I'm a huge fan of [ng-boilerplate](https://github.com/joshdmiller/ng-boilerplate).

It has an awesome modular structure. I prefer it over to stacks or sock drawer.

Comment: `ng-boilerplate` seems to be based on `angular-app`. It's a pretty good structure.

Comment: Or it could be the other way around ;)

Comment: I think `angular-app` has been around for longer, but I could be wrong :P

Comment: Can't say I checked the dates, so I could definitely be wrong.

Comment: main negative is it doesn't have generators but I do like this structure better :-)

Comment: @kenyee, there's been a proposal for this, but it has yet to be fully tackled: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/109

Comment: ngbp is good, but not perfect. It doesn't have a SCSS implementation, does not automatically compile .less (or .scss) files (you have to include them manually) and also has no option to disable grunt tasks within a config. I think to go on with htis boilerplate a few things need to be implemented...

Comment: https://github.com/brnrajoriya/Angular-Ready-To-Use-Boilerplate